Does playwright support windows application scenarios like exe installation, running powershell script or clicking windows application?
I am searching for open source which can be used for functional automation testing tool which can automate Electron application as well windows application automation. So Does playwright support windows application scenarios like exe installation, running powershell script or clicking windows application?
I am able to automate electron application testing using playwright but searching for tools which also can automate windows application interactions as well.

No, Playwright is for web-based apps only.
If you can run your installation with a single command line command, use the node child_process API or an alternative in your language.
For automation of win32, WPF apps - try https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI
